# ANTLR 4 Python Documentation

Tags: python-2.7, compiler-construction, token, antlr4

I am very new to antlr 4 and my target language is PYTHON2.
I am not able to understand CommonTokenStream in python and how I can access tokens in antlr 4.
What I require is to access tokens present in Hidden Channel ?
Please someone point me to some proper documentation where I can understand how to access tokens and manipulate them in python.
I am sorry if the question is vague, I am new here.

Answer (score 0):

The ANTLR book is one. 
https://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference

In the chapter 12 "Wielding Lexical Black Magic", it has "Accessing hidden channel" section. Use the TokenStreamRewriter to rewrite the token.

You need to mentally convert Java code in the book to Python code. The runtime libraries have subtle differences but they are virtually the same.

It is not the only way. You can override lexer's emit() function (which I usually do). Then you have total control over the token routing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on python 3 it is all wonderfully done cooked and ready

https://github.com/jszheng/py3antlr4book

For Some Python start hints try

https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/python-target.md

If you are using Anaconda3 try egrep of class def import comments(#) of all *.py
Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\antlr4_python3_runtime-4.7.1-py3.6.egg\antlr4

Or even write a ANTLR script to create the python docs and share with me and the world

Also at run time this helps to see what methods and properties are in say a CTX object

```
def dump(obj):
  for attr in dir(obj):
    print("obj.%s = %r" % (attr, getattr(obj, attr)))

        print("-------------------------------------------")
        dump(ctx)
        print("===========================================")
```